# await is giving Refrence error in react-native

Tags: react-native

I have the following code

```
async _onPress() {

            NetInfo.isConnected.fetch().then(isConnected => {

                if (isConnected) {
                    fetch(apiURL + '/login', {
                        method: 'POST',
                        headers: {
                            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                        },
                        body: JSON.stringify({
                            username: this.props.username,

                            password: this.props.password
                        })
                    })
                        .then((response) => response.json())
                        .then((responseJson) => {


                            if (responseJson.status === 'success') 
    //I am getting error here
                                await AsyncStorage.setItem('token', responseJson.token);

                                //moving on to the main screen if server return success
                                Actions.MainScreen();


                            } else {
                                Toast.show({
                                    text: "Wrong username or password!",
                                    type: "danger"
                                });
                            }
                        })
                        .catch((error) => {
                              console.log(error);
                        });

                } else {

                    Toast.show({
                        text: "Please Connect To Internet",
                        type: "danger"
                    });

                }

            });

        }
```

I am trying to save the token i receive from my API server using AsyncStorage.I get the following errors

```
    Expression statement is not assignmentor call
```

and `RefrenceError:await is not defined`

when i try to use await in the location.

But when use the same code at the beginning of the function i get no errors.

I dont know what is wrong. Is it not allowed in async await? I am not too familiar with these.

Comment: Your outer function is `async`, but you're inside two layers of non-async functions within that.

Comment: is there any way for me to use that where i want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `_onPress` calls some async functions and you want to wait for all of them to finish, you must place an 'await' in front of every single one of them. In addition, every async function, including async callback functions, must be declared `async` too.

The complete code:

```
async _onPress() {
    **await** NetInfo.isConnected.fetch().then(**async** (isConnected) => {
        if (isConnected) {
            **await** fetch(apiURL + '/login', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    username: this.props.username,
                    password: this.props.password
                })
            })
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then(**async** (responseJson) => {
                if (responseJson.status === 'success') {
                    **await** AsyncStorage.setItem('token', responseJson.token);
                    Actions.MainScreen();
                } else {
                    Toast.show({
                        text: "Wrong username or password!",
                        type: "danger"
                    });
                }
            })
        }
    })
}
```